# probability - defective disks

Tags: probability

70% of disk drives made from Company X function properly. If we have a collection of $5$ disk drives, what is the probability that:

1. At least $1$ disk drive doesn’t function?
2. At least $1$ disk drive is functioning?

This is what I came up with for the first question:
$\small \operatorname{C}(5,1)\!\cdot\!0.3^1\!\cdot\!0.7^4 + \operatorname{C}(5,2)\!\cdot\!0.3^2\!\cdot\!0.7^3 + \operatorname{C}(5,3)\!\cdot\!0.3^3\!\cdot\!0.7^2 + \operatorname{C}(5,4)\!\cdot\!0.3^4\!\cdot\!0.7^1 + \operatorname{C}(5,5)\!\cdot\!0.3^5\!\cdot\!0.7^0$

This is what I came up with for the 2nd question:
$\small \operatorname{C}(5,1)\!\cdot\!0.7^1\!\cdot\!0.3^4 + \operatorname{C}(5,2)\!\cdot\!0.7^2\!\cdot\!0.3^3 + \operatorname{C}(5,3)\!\cdot\!0.7^3\!\cdot\!0.3^2 + \operatorname{C}(5,4)\!\cdot\!0.7^4\!\cdot\!0.3^1 + \operatorname{C}(5,5)\!\cdot\!0.7^5\!\cdot\!0.3^0$

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: $\checkmark$ What you have done is correct, but tedious.  As Alex points out, it can oftimes be easier to work out the probabilities of the complementary event. (In an exam, it will look neater and be less prone to errors.)

Answer (score 1):

1. 1-probability all disks function
2. 1 - probability all disks malfunction.

It's often easier to find the probability of the compliment of the event. Now use the Binomial distribution...